# I'm having some issues with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wanted to give different icons exact color using nth-child,but instead I got that every icon is having the same color as the first one

```
.iconHeader:hover:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}
.iconHeader:hover:nth-child(2) {
  color: pink;
}
.iconHeader:hover:nth-child(3) {
  color: lightblue;
}
.iconHeader:hover:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```
<ul class="social">
   <h1 class="translatedTextY">follow us</h1>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to target `<i>` and not `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to complicate this. Following will work

```
.fa-facebook:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
  color: pink;
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use nth-of-type, rather than nth-child, as it will search for that type of element in the parent div regardless of the other elements in the parent.

I also think you should use your 'social' class, as it is a parent of all the icons, while each iconHeader is only the parent of one icon.

So you could write:

```
.social i:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

and this will target the first child only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are targeting wrong element, you need to add **nth-child to li** instead of **a.iconHeader** and in your **ul** you are adding **h1** so first li will become second child so use **nth-of-type instead of nth-child**

> The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent and The :nth-child(n)
>   selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of
>   type, of its parent.

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) .iconHeader{
  color: blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) .iconHeader{
  color: pink;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) .iconHeader{
  color: lightblue;
}
li:nth-of-type(4) .iconHeader{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<ul class="social">
   <h1 class="translatedTextY">follow us</h1>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="iconHeader"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

sc0rp1on's answer works, but if you are still wondering why :nth-child() didn't, it's because you added the hover state before you selected your nth children. This should work:

```
.iconHeader:nth-child(1):hover {
  color: blue;
}
.iconHeader:nth-child(2):hover {
  color: pink;
}
.iconHeader:nth-child(3):hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
.iconHeader:nth-child(4):hover {
  color: red;
};
```

Because you were adding the hover class before selecting the nth child, the hover state was being applied to the class and thus, all elements containing that class received the hover state.

It may be useful to use nth-child as you won't have to clutter up your HTML (markup) with unnecessary classes in future.